# value is not inserting into array properly

Tags: php, arrays

It is correctly insert the value of $name[$init] into the key dsf under the $val['dsf'] but it is inerting only the last value in dsf under the $val['customProduct']['dsf']

```
$name = array(0=>'Amit',1=>'Amit1',2=>'Amit2');
foreach($order->orderLines as $init =>$val){
        $val['dsf'] = $name[$init];
        $val['customProduct']['dsf'] = $name[$init];
}
```

Comment: $val['customProduct']['dsf'] = $name[$init]; always assigns to the same pointer in the array. Meaning the last value in $name[$init] would always override the previous values

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: see answer below by @dmitry I try to achieve the same thing but it is not working for me.

Comment: Can you explain $orderLines is pregenerated or generate based on $name array

Comment: it is an pre generated array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `$val` pass by reference:

```
$name = array(0=>'Amit',1=>'Amit1',2=>'Amit2');
$orderLines = array(
    array(
        'dsf' => array(),
        'customProduct' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'dsf' => array(),
        'customProduct' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'dsf' => array(),
        'customProduct' => array()
    ),
);
foreach($orderLines as $init => &$val){ //edit here
    $val['dsf']= $name[$init];
    $val['customProduct']['dsf'] = $name[$init];
}

print_r($orderLines);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dsf] => Amit
            [customProduct] => Array
                (
                    [dsf] => Amit
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dsf] => Amit1
            [customProduct] => Array
                (
                    [dsf] => Amit1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dsf] => Amit2
            [customProduct] => Array
                (
                    [dsf] => Amit2
                )

        )

)
```

[See here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: Sorry it is not working in my case. In normal case it seems to be correct and working. But don't know why not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This and In Case If You Have Any Query Just Comment I Am Happy To Answer

```
<?php

$name = array(0=>'Amit',1=>'Amit1',2=>'Amit2');


$orderLines = array(
    array(
        "id"=>1,
        "order_id"=>10,
        "dfs"=>0,
        "customProduct"=>array(
            "id"=>102,
            "order_id"=>10,
            "dfs"=>0,
            "name"=>""
        )
    ),
    array(
        "id"=>2,
        "order_id"=>20,
        "dfs"=>1,
        "customProduct"=>array(
            "id"=>105,
            "order_id"=>20,
            "dfs"=>1,
            "name"=>""
        )
    ),
    array(
        "id"=>3,
        "order_id"=>50,
        "dfs"=>2,
        "customProduct"=>array(
            "id"=>107,
            "order_id"=>50,
            "dfs"=>2,
            "name"=>""
        )
    )
);

$orderLinestemp = array();
foreach($name as $value){
    
    $temp_array = array("dfs"=>$value,"customProduct"=>array("name"=>$value));
    array_push($orderLinestemp, $temp_array);
}

$orderLines=array_replace_recursive($orderLines,$orderLinestemp);

echo "<pre/>";

print_r($orderLines);

?>
```

> output

[image]

Comment: it is not working as order line array already have some values. it is not an empty array

Comment: Can You Give Me Sample of Pregenerated array so i can help you and what is actual problem is

Comment: yes sure. It is a laravel generated object Array

https://prnt.sc/uyx2dt

Comment: Sorry Previous Edited Answer is also not work i again change it please check it now.

Comment: @AmitSharma Can You Check it please and can you give acknowledgment it work or not so i change try other way to solve your problem

Comment: At the moment I have to change it to work other way around. But your solutions does help me. Thanks